# The performance impact of use System.getenv() in java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I have a REST web service in java built with jersey and for security reasons I would like to save in the OS environment variables the parameters of the method: `DriverManager.getConnection();`. Url, username and password.

Since every request needs to create his own connection I want to know if so many calls to `System.getenv("key");` are a performance problem?

The idea of doing so is from this article: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html#java-rds-javase

Would be a better option to have something like this:

```
public class EnvironmentHelper {
    static final String URL;
    static final String USERNAME;
    static final String PASSWORD;

    static {
        URL = System.getenv("URL");
        USERNAME = System.getenv("USERNAME");
        PASSWORD = System.getenv("PASSWORD");
    }
}
```

This way I only load the variables once, right? No matter how many requests I receive.

Comment: Each `System.getenv` should take about as much time as a hash lookup.  The performance impact should be nil.  You should profile it yourself if you're concerned.

Comment: Compared to the overhead of opening the connection, let alone doing anything with it, `getenv()` is utterly insignificant: *however* this technique is no more secure than the usual techniques. If the attacker can get to your `context.xml` file he can get to this.

Comment: @EJP Yes, you are right. The only solution to minimize the impact of opening a connection every time is with a connection pool, right?

Comment: @Luiz That is correct.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[`System.getEnv(name)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html) transaltes to `ProcessEnvironment.getEnv` which is actually a lookup to a HashMap (ProcessEnvironment is an extension of HashMap) This HashMap is loaded in a static block which runs on class initilaization - so this 
looks to be quite fast as lookup is O(1) in high probability.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt that calls to getenv would pose a larger performance issue in comparison to creating a new connection per request, but I believe it will be the best if the problem is approached with the static loading approach you use above. This eliminates the task of searching the environment list for each new connection.

According to the [operating system manual for the getenv function](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getenv.3.html), it does need to search the environment list to find the value, but from my C knowledge I know that this requires no syscalls as the environment variables are copied to the program.

Comment: Because is thread safe, every call has also to lock a mutex, right?

Comment: @Luiz No, it is not thread-safe: 'The implementation of getenv() is not required to be reentrant'.